# How do you find the position of an element in a list if you only name some of that element?

Tags: python, list

For example,

In this list,

```
myFile = ['aweys:5\n', 'baaa: 7\n']
```

How do I find the position of the element containing 'aweys', in the quickest way possible?

I have tried

```
if any('aweys' in s for s in myFile)
```

But am not sure how to find which index in the list the string is at.

Comment: Did you try looping through it and using the `in` operator? If not, what did you try?

Comment: Well first I found that 'aweys' is in the list with this: if any('aweys' in s for s in myFile).

Comment: But I'm not sure how to find the position of element containing 'aweys' with only that information at hand, so not all the contents of the element

Answer (score 3):

```
for i, val in enumerate(myFile):
    if 'aweys' in val:
        print 'aweys is found at index %d' % i
```

Other method to get tuples of index and string

```
print filter(lambda s: 'aweys' in s[1], enumerate(myFile))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def find(value, array):
    index = 0
    for val in array:
        if value in val:
            return index
        index += 1
    return -1
```

This will find first occurence of `value` in `array` and return the location or `-1` if nothing is found.

If you know the exact name of the value you can use `[].index(item_value)`

Comment: is there a quicker/easier way you can think of?

Comment: @Paul Rooney has created a simpler solution if you are familiar with enumeration

Comment: @Aweys: The source code can be shorter (see `enumerate`) but the algorithm cannot. You have to visit all elements (until you find the matching one) and you have to look for the substring there.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys, I'll use Paul's one

Answer (score 1):

For a list containing tuples with each index (in case it is found more than once) and the full value, try the following:

```
>>> myFile = ['aweys:5\n', 'baaa: 7\n']
>>> found = [(i, v) for i, v in enumerate(myFile) if 'aweys' in v]
>>> print(found)
[(0, 'aweys:5\n')]
```